# Android Studio (how can i fix it?)

Tags: java, android-styles

How can I align the Password textbox to the Username textbox to look like [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41cP0.png) or what can I do to fix it?

**Code**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/aduser"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/userconfig1"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="#000000"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/adpass"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:hint="Password"

    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aduser" >

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_info_24"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

How can my design be improved? I apologize; I'm new to Android Studio and am currently testing designs.

The design I expect is that the username and password are *equal* and the color of the password is not far from the username, and the show/hide password is enabled.

Comment: don't post images of text

Comment: How about that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".InterstitialAdsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/aduserL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/aduser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/adpass"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aduserL"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

if you some video recommend watch this [youtubeVideo](https://youtu.be/EKIgPueafIU?si=xv_Q8EsoaYXDgxK-)

[image: output]